# How to choose Kafka topic dynamically with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Event class.

```
class Event {
    String destination;
}
```

The destination property is the name of Kafka topic.

How can I publish a message to the destination.

I can't put the destination in application.properties because the destination was set in program.

Answer (score 0):

Since you determine the destination dynamically, you would need `BinderAwareChannelResolver` in your application.

Something similar to [router sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/blob/master/router-sink/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/module/router/sink/RouterSink.java#L60) application. You can check